# Adjust vertical grid in ggplot (R) to match desired values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Second post in StackOverflow so my apologies for not been clear enoguh.

I need to modify the vertical  grid in ggplot to match  the beginning and the end of certain repetitive period (each dar or each 24h). I have been looking but I cannot find anything similar. I attach a code to run the problem:

```
mydate <- seq(ISOdate(2016,1,1), ISOdate(2016,2,1), by = "hour") # or "3 months"
mysample <- runif(n = length(mydate), min = 1, max = 10)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate,mysample)
mygraph <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes (x = mydate)) +
              geom_line(aes(y = mysample, colour = "red")) +
              ggtitle("MyTry") +
              labs(x="Day of the Month", y= "MyValue") +
              theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray50", size = 0.1), 
                    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
                    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
                    panel.background = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="gray", size = 10),
                    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 5, size = 9),
                    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, vjust = 1))
mygraph
```

Whichs gives:

[Random values for each hour of a month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi3my.png)

I would appreciate if anybody could help me out with any of these two questions:

1-. Is it posible to modify the vertical grid (in my plot there are just 5)  in such a way so it matches every beginning of a day (i.e the 00:00:00 time) or should I create data and plot it to "simulate" a grid (anyidea on this would be aprreciated also)

2-. Instead of "ene04" , "ene 11", "ene 18"... in te X axis, is there a way to put all de days (not the hours)? So it apperas "ene 01" "ene 02" etc?

I hope I have make it clear enough so someone can help me!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control ticks with `scale_x_timedate` alson with some adjustments in `axis.text.x` and `axis.ticks.x`, you can get the result pasted below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
mydate <- seq(ISOdate(2016,1,1), ISOdate(2016,2,1), by = "hour") # or "3 months"
mysample <- runif(n = length(mydate), min = 1, max = 10)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate,mysample)
mygraph <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes (x = mydate)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mysample, colour = "red")) +
  ggtitle("MyTry") +
  labs(x="Day of the Month", y= "MyValue") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%b-%d"), breaks=pretty_breaks(n = 32)(as_datetime(c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01")))) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray50", size = 0.1), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="gray", size = 10),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 270, vjust = -.5),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, vjust = 1),)
mygraph
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This will be usefull.